# How to Abort Long running Ajax Request in .net MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, abort

I've found several answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914728/how-do-you-cancel-an-ajax-long-running-mvc-action-client-side-in-javascript) and also [this one](http://asprogramming.blogspot.com.tr/2012/02/ajax-call-cancelation-in-mvc.html). But for some reason `this.Response.IsClientConnected` still goes as `true`.

Here is my Client:

```
<div class="ajax-loader-gif-close" id="cancelBusy">Close</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("List", "Visit", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formFilter" }))
    {
       //Some models some TextBoxFor  etc.
    }

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var ajaxCallObject = null;

    $(document).ready(function () {
         $('form').submit(function () {
                ajaxCallObject = $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        toggleBusyIndicator();
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        toggleBusyIndicator();
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        //Some stuff
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        }
        $("#cancelBusy").click(function () {
             ajaxCallObject.abort();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Server-Side:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult List(VisitFilterViewModel model)
{
      //IsClientConnected is ALWAYS TRUE even though I abort from client
      while (this.Response.IsClientConnected)
      {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
      }

      return PartialView("PartialVisitFilterList", model);
}
```

With FireBug I see that the action is Aborted, but `IsClientConnected` is still `true`. What am I doing wrong?

Note: If you consider removing `[HttpPost]` attribute to solve this, I've already tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](http://d585tldpucybw.cloudfront.net/forums/cancel-button-on-progressarea-to-stop-a-long-running-process) I finally solved it!
Actually, what I did was completely working but since I was running this in my local computer with VS Development, the Response was never ended. But, when I put it on IIS Server, everything worked out just fine.

In case site or the post is deleted, I'm posting the answer here:

> The Cancel button is working fine when the application is hosted on
>   IIS. If you are testing on the VS development server the
>   Response.IsClientConnected will always be true. Keep in mind that in
>   the previous versions of the RadProgressArea the cancellation is not
>   working under Chrome. For Q2.2014 this will be resolved. You could
>   test our internal build for this.